# Pyspark: Add a new column to dataframe if value in some of its columns matches another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Note: I have 20 columns and millions of rows.

```
df_a = spark.createDataFrame([('A', 'X', 1), ('B', 'Y', 2), ('G', 'W', 7)], ["val_1", "val_2", "unique_ID"])
df_a.show()
+-----+-----+---------+
|val_1|val_2|unique_ID|
+-----+-----+---------+
|    A|    X|        1|
|    B|    Y|        2|
|    G|    W|        7|
+-----+-----+---------+


df_b = spark.createDataFrame([('A', 'X'), ('B', 'Y'), ('G', 'W'),('B', 'Y'),('A', 'X'), ('G', 'W'), ('G', 'W')], ["val_1", "val_2"])
df_b.show()

+-----+-----+
|val_1|val_2|
+-----+-----+
|    A|    X|
|    B|    Y|
|    G|    W|
|    B|    Y|
|    A|    X|
|    G|    W|
|    G|    W|
+-----+-----+

#Expected result:

+-----+-----+-----+---------+
|sl.no|val_1|val_2|unique_ID|
+-----+-----+-----+---------+
|    1|    A|    X|        1|
|    2|    B|    Y|        2|
|    3|    G|    W|        7|
|    4|    B|    Y|        2|
|    5|    A|    X|        1|
|    6|    G|    W|        7|
|    7|    G|    W|        7|
+-----+-----+-----+---------+
```

I want to create column unique_ID in spark dataframe (as shown in  result above), if val_1 and val_2 matches df_b then create a unqiue_ID based on df_a.

Comment: how would you want the `sl.no` column look like?  Is it just an index without any particular ordering?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two dataframes using `val_1` and `val_2`:

```
result = df_a.join(df_b, ['val_1', 'val_2'])

result.show()
+-----+-----+---------+
|val_1|val_2|unique_ID|
+-----+-----+---------+
|    A|    X|        1|
|    A|    X|        1|
|    B|    Y|        2|
|    B|    Y|        2|
|    G|    W|        7|
|    G|    W|        7|
|    G|    W|        7|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

If you want to add an index column, you can use `F.monotonically_increasing_id()`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df_a.join(df_b, ['val_1', 'val_2']).withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())

result.show()
+-----+-----+---------+------------+
|val_1|val_2|unique_ID|          id|
+-----+-----+---------+------------+
|    A|    X|        1| 25769803776|
|    A|    X|        1| 25769803777|
|    B|    Y|        2|257698037760|
|    B|    Y|        2|257698037761|
|    G|    W|        7|472446402560|
|    G|    W|        7|472446402561|
|    G|    W|        7|472446402562|
+-----+-----+---------+------------+
```

Comment: It would be great to mark as duplicate and close this kind of question. I already see may similar questions

Comment: @koiralo it's a bit different. It seems the OP wants to add an index column as well, but I just want to clarify that first.

Comment: You can still mark it as duplicate and add a comment if needed for some change.